# What can replace desktop gadget for Windows 8?

Tags: c#, widget, windows-8, windows-desktop-gadgets

I was looking forward to use W8. I always assumed that 'live tiles' are direct analog of Android widgets - ie small self-sufficient app which shows its content entirely inside small screen area....

however I just learned that it is not the case and live tiles are not designed for that...

have I missed something ? is there a specific new feature I can use to program a 'widget' (or Vista gadget if you like) ? (preferably using C#) - so it can be placed on the Start screen along the other tiles and display real-time information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to develop a WinRT app.  This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386) will get you started on how that is done, but it does support XAML / C# as well as HTML / Javascript.  Keep in mind though that the live tiles aren't really updated in realtime - they are updated every 30 minutes or through a push provider.

Comment: thanks Jeff but I already knew that link.. could you please point specifically to an article that explains what type of app should I create in VS2012 to make it work as a widget on W8 RT ? P.S. I also know about the notifications but from MS articles live tiles must not do what I want as a widget. A tile is a gateway into application, I want simple stuff like a clock or a weather widget on the Start screen (not on lock screen)..

Comment: That's the thing - there is no differentiation from a widget or a live tile on the start screen.  They are the same thing.

Comment: Check out the Templates for Windows Store Apps in Visual Studio 2012.  There are XAML C# templates that can get you pointed in the right direction.  Here is a link that will help you create your first tile and update it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465437.aspx

Comment: So if I'd like to create a clock tile with seconds - are you saying that a live tile will have to get XML notification each second? Is that you thing the way to develop a widget? also as I stated in the question - MS specifically outlined design decision making and tiles ARE NOT widgets.. this is why I asked - what else could it be? and if none - then there is no widgets on W8 is there?

Comment: I haven't seen the ability to send the XML notification every second, especially if the app is running in the background.  You are correct that tiles are not widgets.  Here is a sample on how to update tiles: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Tile-updates-from-2f6a854c

There aren't widgets in Windows 8, but you can accomplish what you want similar to the sidebar in Windows 7 with 8Gagdet - a third party app.  http://8gadgetpack.bplaced.net/

Comment: yes Jeff thank you... I was just hoping that I missed something and there is a widget replacement in the W8... Mobile OS without widget seems crazy to me! :) cheers